# Why can't I initialize a Python queue twice in the same program?

Tags: queue, python-3.5

When my program is the following...

```
import queue
queue = queue.Queue()
queue = None
queue = queue.Queue()
```

...my output is the following:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Queue'

---

But when my program is the following...

```
import queue
queue = queue.Queue()
queue = None
```

...no error messages are thrown.

---

Why is this the case? I need to reinitialize my queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you imported the module `queue`, you actually created a variable `queue` referencing an object of type `module`.
Then, when you created a queue named `queue`, you *redefined* the variable `queue` to be an object of type `queue.Queue`.
No wonder why you could not call `queue.Queue()` after that!
QED.

See in details:

```
>>> import queue
>>> type(queue)
<class 'module'>
>>> # Here you redefine the variable queue: the module queue won't be accessible after that
>>> queue = queue.Queue()
>>> type(queue)
<class 'queue.Queue'>
>>> queue
<queue.Queue object at ***>
>>> # Here I try to call Queue() on an object of type Queue...
>>> queue = queue.Queue()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'Queue'
>>> queue = None
>>> # And here I try to call Queue() on an object of type None...
>>> queue = queue.Queue()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Queue'
```

Comment: Well that was a very easy solution. I can't believe I overlooked it. Thanks.